# ionic 3 menu swipe conflict with item-sliding underneath

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, menu, swipe, ionic3

I have slide menu and a list page with ionic's item-sliding listening to ionDrag and ionSwipe which executes certain methods.

When I slide from left to right and start from too left of the screen, it will open the menu AND trigger the swipe gestures from the list.

Is there a way to set the width of the "strip" on the left-side of screen which listens for the swipe to open the menu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listeners to document for touchstart and touchend events, then in touchstart handler you can check if target contains your component elementref then disable the menu-swipe gesture using GestureController and on touchend you enable the gesture again.

```
private touchEnd(ev: Event) {
    if(this.appMenuIsDisabled) {
        this.gestureCtrl.enableGesture('menu-swipe', 10);
        this.appMenuIsDisabled = false;
    }
}

private touchStart(ev: Event) {
    if (!this.appMenuIsDisabled && this.elem.nativeElement.contains(ev.target)) {
        this.gestureCtrl.disableGesture('menu-swipe', 10);
        this.appMenuIsDisabled = true;
    }

}
```